# what is conv1/weights/Adam in checkpoint file in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I printed all tensor value in a checkpoint file.

I can understand "conv1/weights". But what is "conv1/weights/Adam" in checkpoint file?

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer, you should accept it. You could also add your own

Answer (score 1):

It's an extra variable that was created because you are using an `AdamOptimizer()` to train your data. You can read about the algorithm in the original paper - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980v8.pdf